# Delete a Push Subscription from Subscriber using T-SQL in Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, replication, subscription, merge-replication

I have a Publisher server and Subscriber Server which are synchronized using Merge replication. When i using wizard to remove Replication a login window ask me to login on Subscriber Server and remove its subscription but when I using generated script for removing Replication, the subscription in subscriber won't remove. How can I do it using TSQL?
In Other Word:
I want to **Connect to subscriber and delete record of subscription at subscriber also** using T-SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found the solution of my problem:

I used Linked Server to create a connection to remote server:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver 'RemoteServer\PeerInstance', N'SQL Server'

exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'RemoteServer\PeerInstant', 'true', 'sa', 'password'

exec ReplicatedDBOnMainServer.sys.sp_dropmergesubscription
@publication = N'PublicationName', 
@subscriber = N'RemoteServer\PeerInstant'

exec [RemoteServer\PeerInstant].ReplicatedDBOnRemote.sys.sp_mergesubscription_cleanup
@publisher = N'MainServer\MainInstant', 
@publisher_db = N'ReplicatedDBOnMainServer'
@publication = N'PublicationName'
```

Answer (score 1):

To drop a Merge push subscription you must to connect to both the Publisher and Subscriber.  Per [How to: Delete a Push Subscription (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146944.aspx) - execute [sp_dropmergesubscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176045.aspx) at the Publisher and [sp_mergesubscription_cleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188391.aspx) at the Subscriber.

Comment: That's the exact answers but I said I want to connect to subscriber using TSQL and then execute sp_mergesubscription_cleanup. In fact I want execute the command remotely. How should I do this ?

Comment: If you can connect to the Publisher from the Subscriber then you can execute sp_dropmergesubscription, then execute sp_mergesubscription_cleanup at the Subscriber.  I usually have a connection open to both Publishers and Subscribers in SSMS when performing replication maintenance such as this.